# How to click through a transparent SVG object to a SVG object that it overlays?

Tags: css, svg

I have a windows application ( no source code ) that allows you to import stencils ( SVG ) into a SQL database. From there, the application let's you insert them into a drawing surface. You could have multiple stencils layer on top of each other. If there is any transparency, you should be able to click through to the select the stencil underneath.

There is a stored procedure that runs every so often that changes out stencils for a different version based on certain criteria. I've had issues with distortion going from one stencil's height/width to another's as well as inserted stencils not centering over the stencil it's being layered upon.

I had to figure out a way to solve both problems. What I came up with probably isn't the correct way, but I am no SVG guru. Just setting the height and width of the root `svg` object in the stencils didn't fix anything, so I added (what I thought was) a transparently filled `rect` and set the height and width of that to the same value as the root `svg` object. This way, no matter what the stored procedure switched to, the stencil was guaranteed to be centered.

Everything looked great and I thought I was done. However, the fixed width created a rectangle that had clickable blank space, even though I had set the `rect` to `fill:none;stroke:none;stroke-width:0;`; you can't click anything underneath that stencil.

**What do I need to do to be able to truly make the stencil respect its height and width on resize while allowing click through on "transparent" blank space to select the stencil underneath?**

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/code_maverick/pen/EZPLNY?editors=1000#0)

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" version="1.1" 
     width="60" viewBox="0 0 60 30" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">

  <style type="text/css">
  <![CDATA[
    .st1 {fill:none;stroke:#0000ff;stroke-dasharray:1.2,2.4;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:1.2}
    .st2 {fill:none;stroke:none;stroke-width:0;}
  ]]>
  </style>

  <g>
    <rect class="st2" height="30" width="60" x="0" y="0" />
  </g>

  <g>
    <path class="st1" d="m 20,15 a 10,10 0 1 1 20,0 10,10 0 1 1 -20,0 z" />
  </g>

</svg>
```

P.S. I seemingly have to use `path` instead of `circle`, as the application does not handle the newer version of SVG very well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm even worst at SVG, but would [`pointer-events:none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events#Values) work for you? This would make the element not accept any mouse events: click, hover, etc.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Alas, this had zero effect on our issue.